# Component load before data load in Angular

Tags: angular, angularjs, metronic

Is anyone using [Metronic Theme](https://preview.keenthemes.com/metronic8/demo1/index.html) ?

In the metronic theme components load before data loads from API and data doesn't update after data is changed.

Where I tried another theme named [DashPlex](https://spruko.com/demo/dashplex/Dashplex/html/index.html) and it's working fine.

I have used the same module, service, and component. What could be the reason for this issue? I could use a resolver in Metronic to fix it, but I want to know how does it working fine in Dashplex. I haven't seen any different configurations between these themes.

In Dashplex component, data automatically update when data load complete.